# Nested generic constraints in f#

Tags: generics, f#

I'm trying to define an extension method on a generic class, (`Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.NumericUpDown`), but restrict that generic to `Nullable<_>`, however I can't figure out the syntax.  The essence of what I want is

```
type NumericUpDown<Nullable<_>> with
  member x.getVal() = x.Value.GetValueOrDefault()
  member x.setVal v = x.Value <- Nullable v
```

but that won't compile.  I've tried several variations on that theme, but nothing works.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi - I saw to late that you want a extension method - but sadly I don't know the the class you are trying to extent enough to show code. The best I could give is a runtime check (`match x with | :? System.Nullable<'a> as nA -> nA.Value.GetValueOrDefault() | _ -> Unchecked.defaultof<'a>`)

Comment: This isn't possible with F#-style extensions. You can't extend a specific case of a generic type.

Comment: @Daniel just fyi see below.

Comment: Right. It's possible with .NET-style extensions (via `ExtensionAttribute`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the class you want to extend but as from F# 3.1 you should be able to write and consume this:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type NumericUpDownExtensions () =
  [<Extension>]
  static member getVal(x: NumericUpDown<Nullable<'a>>) = x.Value.GetValueOrDefault()
  [<Extension>]
  static member setVal(x: NumericUpDown<Nullable<'a>>, v) = x.Value <- Nullable v
```